# How do I get an unauthorized M4P file onto an iOS device?

Tags: ios, itunes, drm

We're trying to reproduce a bug which causes our app to crash when it accesses a M4P file (MPEG-4 Protected file, a DRM protected file from the old iTunes days. Ummmm, yeah.).

We got such a culprit file sent to us by one of our in-the-wild testers, and now we're trying to put it onto a test device in order to debug, but here's the snag: iTunes *insists* on authorizing the file using the AppleID that purchased it, otherwise it won't sync it to the device. We don't have the user's AppleID details, and I don't think it's appropriate to even ask him for it.

Is there some other way of getting that file onto the device? I'd rather not jailbreak the device, but am willing to consider that option.

Comment: iTunes dropped the DRM a while ago. These old DRMed files aren't available for purchase any more. At least not for music.

Comment: As @Almo says - DRM is no longer available for purchase on the iTunes store (at least not for music, which is what we need).